# ReactJS: What do first parameter in addEventListener, ReactDOM.render(), and () mean in return statement?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I'm studying ReactJS and came across the following component example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // set the default internal state
        this.state = {
            clicks: 0
        };

        this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refs.myComponentDiv.addEventListener(
            ‘click’, 
            this.clickHandler
        );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.refs.myComponentDiv.removeEventListener(
            ‘click’, 
            this.clickHandler
        );
    }

    clickHandler() {
        this.setState({
            clicks: this.clicks + 1
        });
    }

    render() {
        let children = this.props.children;

        return (
            <div className=”my-component” ref=”myComponentDiv”>
                <h2>My Component ({this.state.clicks} clicks})</h2>
                <h3>{this.props.headerText}</h3>
                {children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What is the first parameter, `'click'`, mean in `this.refs.myComponentDiv.removeEventListener()` and `this.refs.myComponentDiv.removeEventListener()`? And why do you have to pass in `props` to `super()`? And what does the `()` mean in `({this.state.clicks} clicks})`?

Lastly, I came across a stateless component:

```
const StatelessCmp = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className=”my-stateless-component”>
            {props.name}: {props.birthday}
        </div>
    );
};

// ---
ReactDOM.render(
    <StatelessCmp name=”Art” birthday=”10/01/1980” />,
    document.getElementById(“main”)
);
```

And when do you choose to use a stateless component? And when do you use and what does `ReactDOM.render()` do, especially the `document.getElementById(“main”)` portion? Because typically, you would simply do `export default ...`.

And in the following, will simply the two `<p>'s` be displayed on top of the `<MyComponent/>` class?

```
<MyComponent headerText=”A list of paragraph tags”>
    <p>First child.</p>
    <p>Any other <span>number</span> of children...</p>
</MyComponent>
```

Thank you and will be sure to upvote and accept answer!

Answer (score 0):

1. 'click' is the name of the click event which is created when you click in the viewport/element
2. As you are extending the class React.Component you have to pass the properties of your class to the super class (React.Component) that it is correctly instantiated. For more infos read a book about Object oriented programming
3. I cannot find the statement `({this.state.clicks} clicks})` in your code.
4. If you do not use `this.state` use a stateless component
5. ReactDOM.render() actually creates and renders your components to your page. The document.findElementById('main') is looking for the html element with id="main" that ReactDOM can render it into this element.

I would recommend that you read a basic book or take a online tutorial in javascript first before you learn a js framework like React